# How can i use 2 picker view in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uipickerview

I want to use two picker view in one xib. How can i do that ?

Comment: Is your actual problem is how you would create the delegates for the two picker views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use single PickerView for two operations- Pass Array Values with Tag Values

for First Operation :

```
self.pickerView = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"France", @"Italy", @"California", @"", nil];
self.pickerView.tag = 111;
```

For second operation:

```
self.pickerView = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:your array values, @"",nil];
self.pickerView.tag = 222;
```

Then in

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:           (NSInteger)component
{


    if (self.pickerView.tag == 111) {

        NSLog(@"First Picker View selected Value")
    }
    else if(self.pickerView.tag == 222){

        NSLog(@"Second Picker View Selected Value")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add two `UIPickerView` and create two properties for them like bellow

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView* pv1;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView* pv2;
```

and then work with them.

Comment: @ViTi Brother: How can i load values ?

Comment: How you load for one UIPickerView in same way to both.

Comment: Sorry but I think that Hi, I want to use two picker view in one xib. How can i do that ? The answer on this question is You can add two UIPickerView and create two properties for them like bellow

 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView* pv1;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView* pv2;
and then work with them. This one !!! I Think ...

Comment: Brother: yup you gave the right answer and may be i'm unable to explain my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to load pv1 then call

```
[pv1 reloadAllComponents];
```

and when you want to load pv2 then call

```
[pv2 reloadAllComponents];
```